# How to avoid in unittest Error: Invalid type: ZuoraObject.ConvertToZuoraInvoiceDatas

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, zuora

I have a following class with method

```
public virtual class ZuoraObject  {
..
    public static List<InvoiceData> ConvertToZuoraInvoiceDatas(List<Zuora.zObject> zInvoiceDatas) {
        if (zInvoiceDatas == null) 
            return null;
        List<InvoiceData> invoiceDatas = new List<InvoiceData>();
        for(Zuora.zObject zObj : zInvoiceDatas) {
            invoiceDatas.add(new InvoiceData(zObj));
        }
        return invoiceDatas;
    }
..
}
```

How do I write a unittest for this. I tried below but get the error:
Invalid type: ZuoraObject.ConvertToZuoraInvoiceDatas

```
  @isTest
private static void ConvertToZuoraInvoiceDatasTest() { 
    Zuora.zObject zZObj = new Zuora.zObject('InvoiceData');
    List<Zuora.zObject> listZobj = new List<Zuora.zObject>();
    listZobj.add(zZObj);
    Test.startTest();
    ZuoraObject.ConvertToZuoraInvoiceDatas cInvData = new ZuoraObject.ConvertToZuoraInvoiceDatas(listZobj);
    Test.stopTest();
system.assert(cInvData != null);  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at below line in your test class:-

```
ZuoraObject.ConvertToZuoraInvoiceDatas cInvData = new ZuoraObject.ConvertToZuoraInvoiceDatas(listZobj);
```

You are basically trying to call a static method in wrong way as you are trying to create the instance of the method. To call a static method of apex class, you should simply do like:-

```
ZuoraObject.ConvertToZuoraInvoiceDatas(listZobj);
```

> Basically, If myStaticMethod() is a static method,
>   myClassInstance.myStaticMethod() is not legal. Instead, refer to those
>   static identifiers using the class: MyClass.myStaticVariable and
>   MyClass.myStaticMethod().

Read here about [Static and Instance Methods, Variables, and Initialization Code](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm)